# Error message when using Polls Application In Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Recently, I received a ticket from the end user; he complained he could not use the Microsoft Poll Application in the shared channel.

when I create a Poll in the channel and submit a vote, I receive the error message " Something went wrong. Please try again," as you can see in the attached picture.

I am not sure if this is related to the Shared channel, and I could not find any source from Microsoft to confirm it.

I tried to uninstall and install app. delete the cache also using web version of Teams all have same result

Comment: Currently Polls app is not supported in Teams shared channel. The following apps are supported for use in shared channels - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/shared-channels#supported-apps-in-shared-channels